# Building Floor Plan map using OpenLayers and json

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, geoext, ext-js, html5

How to show map of building floor plan using OpenLayers and json.
moreover, i want to know that how to change features dynamically with zoom based from json files. Let's take example,

Initial the polygon of building feature shows then,
second zoom, detailing map with more features like sitting arragement with desk and chairs, then
third zoom, more detailing with attributes of each sitting arragement.

Above mention zoom level have different type of symbology of each.

How to make this, pl. help me on this..

Regards 
GIS User

Comment: So far people have answered most of your questions, but you haven't rewarded any of them with an *accept*. See if any of your previous questions has recieved an answer worth accepting - thus improving your *accept-rate*.

Answer (score 8):

For the OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON feature collection use an OpenLayers.Layer.Vector instance. Examples from the OpenLayers Examples Gallery:

- https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html
- http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-formats.html
- http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html

Use a zoom based strategy for displaying your layers. This can be achieved using the minScale and maxScale properties in the options object passed to an OpenLayers.Layer.Vector instance.

- http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.minScale